# Accessing attributes by relative :id in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, view

I have a sidebar that displays a `:users` `:shopping_lists`. Upon clicking on the link for a list, the user is directed to a view with an address of: "/shopping_lists/1", where 1 represents the :id of the shopping list. I want to now display all list items that belong to that list in this new view. I'm struggling to figure out how to display those list items that correspond to the relative shopping list. What rails method would I use to accomplish something like this? My associations are already in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your associations are already in place, in your controller you can do:

```
@list_items = ShoppingList.find(params[:id]).list_items
```

Then you can render @list_items into a template however you like, using [collections](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) for instance.

This is assuming you have already defined a belongs_to :shopping_list association in a model called ListItem and a has_many :list_items in your ShoppingList model.